# How can I reduce code with PrimeFaces and JSF?

Tags: jsf

Now I work with JSF and Primefaces, how can I reduce code when I use panel to show list member edit, delete and add? I have 10 panels in 1 page, because I want to create application the same desktop (Ubuntu desktop, Windows desktop, Mac desktop). If I have 10 panels in one page, then I must repeat the same code 10 times to create and handle 10 panels.

How can I reduce this code?

Answer (score 0):

Put that code in an [include or a tag file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen) and then render it in a `<c:forEach>` or `<ui:repeat>` loop which is feeded by a list containing 10 items providing the model for those panels.

Basic kickoff example with a tag file in an `<ui:repeat>`:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.panels}" var="panel">
    <my:panel value="#{panel}" />
</ui:repeat>
```